# Help to identify sound in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, ventilation, sounds

I have a manufactured home. I hear a sound that resembles a wooden ball dropping on a hard surface, it seems to bounce as well, sometimes multiple times a day. It sounds like a croquet ball bouncing on a hardwood floor.

I am  not sure what it is perhaps a valve for gas to escape.

There is   a utility laundry room adjacent to this bathroom. It sounds like it is possibly coming from in the wall but have never heard it when in bathroom but hear it from my bedroom at random times.

Comment: Expansion/contraction of heating system components? Like ductwork? Does it happen when your heating system comes on?

Comment: What kind of heating system do you have?

Comment: No it doesnt seem to be tied to the heating system as it comes on during random times and the noise sounds like it is coming from the side toward the side of the bathroom the outside wall is connected to, the opposite side the vent from the forced air heat pump system is coming in by. I know there is a pipe abs i believe running up inside the wall between the bathroom and the laundry room must be an exhaust pipe. I was hoping someone who has has plumbing experience would let me know if that was possibly the source.

Comment: The door of a washer/dryer being flung open? Test.